# Can't get dhcp ip in my virtual machine on Virtual box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip

I have a copy of a debian virtual machine that i got from my friend. He said that all the package that required for a networking are all in there, in that virtual machine which he gave (i.e SSH package, Web server, SQL server, Mail server etc ). I tried that on my own virtual box. It's run like normal, but the problem is i alwasy got the ip of my friend dhcp ip for my virtual machine.

I got this ip for my vm.

```
address 10.0.2.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.2.255
```

i set my connection virtual machine to NAT, but it didnt change anything, but i cant connect to the internet, but the ip that i get is still the same. While computer ip for my network is (i am using wifi for this case)

```
address 192.168.8.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.8.1
```

why my virtual machine always got the last ip of my friend ip ? what could go wrong with my configuration ? I have tried to restart the network but it seems it didnt change anything like

```
Service networking restart/reload
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart/reload
```

What i expect is my vm got the ip from my network ip for example like this

```
address 192.168.8.101/105
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.8.1
```

Note: i can ping 8.8.8.8 through that network (`address 10.0.2.15`) from my vm, but i cant ping my vm through my own pc ( from the same network, i tried to `ping 10.0.2.15` ) but nothing happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, i got the solution, **i just changed** my connection **from NAT** to **Bridge/NAT network**. From virtual box [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_udp_tunnel).

> **NAT EXPLANATION**
>
> Network Address Translation (NAT) is the simplest way of accessing an
>   external network from a virtual machine. Usually, it does not require
>   any configuration on the host network and guest system. For this
>   reason, it is the default networking mode in VirtualBox.
>
> A virtual machine with NAT enabled acts much like a real computer that
>   connects to the Internet through a router. The "router", in this case,
>   is the VirtualBox networking engine, which maps traffic from and to
>   the virtual machine transparently. In VirtualBox this router is placed
>   between each virtual machine and the host. This separation maximizes
>   security since by default virtual machines cannot talk to each other.
>
> The disadvantage of NAT mode is that, much like a private network
>   behind a router, the virtual machine is invisible and unreachable from
>   the outside internet; you cannot run a server this way unless you set
>   up port forwarding (described below).
>
> **BRIDGE EXPLANATION**
>
> With bridged networking, VirtualBox uses a device driver on your host
>   system that filters data from your physical network adapter. This
>   driver is therefore called a "net filter" driver. This allows
>   VirtualBox to intercept data from the physical network and inject data
>   into it, effectively creating a new network interface in software.
>   When a guest is using such a new software interface, it looks to the
>   host system as though the guest were physically connected to the
>   interface using a network cable: the host can send data to the guest
>   through that interface and receive data from it. This means that you
>   can set up routing or bridging between the guest and the rest of your
>   network.

And it looks like, when we setting the VM connection to NAT, it will give us a default static ip like `10.0.2.15` with gateway `10.0.2.2` based on this [topic](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=49066).

As i said in my question (Quoted):

> I tried that on my own virtual box. It's run like normal, but the
>   problem is i always **got the ip of my friend DHCP IP** for my virtual
>   machine.

I said that the IP `10.0.2.15` is my friends previous IP, while that was incorrect since the `10.0.2.15` IP was actually a default static IP that were automatically given from VirtualBox app when you used the NAT connection for your Virtual Machine.

On the linked topic said:

> In NAT mode, the guest network interface is assigned to the IPv4 range
>   10.0.x.0/24 by default where x corresponds to the instance of the NAT interface +2. So x is 2 when there is only one NAT instance active. In
>   that case the guest is assigned to the address 10.0.2.15, the gateway
>   is set to 10.0.2.2 and the name server can be found at 10.0.2.3.

Comment: The difference is that a Bridge connection makes the VM connect to your actual (real) network. The primary router, or primary DHCP server, see's the VM as a real end device and gives the VM networking information just like it would any other device connecting to it. The NAT mode is where VirtualBox creates a virtual network and the VM pulls DHCP information from the virtual network. No other devices can ping a NAT'd VM, but they can a bridged connection.

Comment: There are nat and nat networkinf , do these connection same ?

Comment: No, they're not the same.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson So whats the difference between these type of connection?

Comment: Read through VirtualBox documentation starting with 6.2 and it explains everything you're asking.https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: However, the difference is that with nat network, you setup a "virtual router" that hands out DHCP addresses so virtual machines on the same host can communicate with each other.